# Migrating MVC project from local to Azure - SQL Server troubles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I am trying to publish my site to the web using Azure and Visual Studio. Previous to this I've been developing on my local machine using a local DB. I've been using Entity Framework and the code first model.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure) to try and set up my site. The site works and I can access it through the *.azurewebsites.net domain.

My problem is that whenever I do anything relating to database access such as signing up for an account, the site gives me a blank 404 page. I'm watching the database and the tables aren't being created as they do normally with Entity Framework. I don't care about losing the local database data - it's all just test stuff.

In my project I have a file called MySiteName - Web Deploy.pubxml which contains the correct connection string.

I can connect to the Azure SQL Server from SSMS on my local machine so there isn't any problem there.

How should I go about troubleshooting this? I'm completely new to Azure so I don't have any idea where to start.

Comment: You can deploy it as Azure Web Role and use VS remote debugging to check what is happening during run time. Make sure you deploy the package under debug mode and enable remote debugger

Answer (score 0):

In Web Config file, add

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

First find error, after try to clear